# How to Print ONLY Column Value between two matched columns

Tags: text-processing

I am Having a file `/tmp/ggloc.log` which contains following data

```
$ cat /tmp/ggloc.log
oracle    12061      1  1 Sep08 ?        10:44:07 ./mgr PARAMFILE /oracle/gg/dirprm/mgr.prm REPORTFILE /oracle/gg/dirrpt/MGR.rpt PROCESSID MGR USESUBDIRS
oracle    75841  75810  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 grep -i mgr
postfix  103283 103268  0 Feb24 ?        00:02:18 qmgr -l -t unix -u
oracle   185935      1  0 Sep08 ?        00:14:14 ./mgr PARAMFILE /oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME/dirprm/mgr.prm REPORTFILE /oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME/dirrpt/MGR.rpt PROCESSID MGR
```

So from above file , I want below output

```
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

I have tried as below

```bsh
k=$(cat /tmp/ggloc.log)
echo "$k" | sed 's/.*PARAMFILE \(.*\) REPORTFILE.*/\1/' | awk -F "/dirprm" '{print $1}'
```

and I am getting below output

```
/oracle/gg
oracle    75841  75810  0 13:55 ?        00:00:00 grep -i mgr
postfix  103283 103268  0 Feb24 ?        00:02:18 qmgr -l -t unix -u
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

So how do I get only

```
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

Need your inputs

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please explain how the lines you are interested in are distinct from the others. It seems that you want those lines where the command starts with `./mgr PARAMFILE`. If so, please state it explicitly - currently it is only implied in your somewhat involved `echo | sed | awk` pipeline and might be overlooked. Also, which of the _two_ occurences of the `/oracle/<dirname>` pattern are relevant here - or can we assume that they are always the same?

Comment: Your log file seems to be the output from a `ps` command. Would it not be easier to look at where the `oracle` user executes those commands and extract the information from the same sources as that instead?

Answer (score 6):

I *think* that you want to find lines that have the word `PARAMFILE` and then print the longest string that comes after `PARAMFILE` and a space, until the last `/dirprm`. If so, you can try:

```
$ sed -En 's/.*PARAMFILE (.*)\/dirprm.*/\1/p' file
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

Or, if your `sed` doesn't support `-E`:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*PARAMFILE \(.*\)\/dirprm.*/\1/p' file
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

or even

```
$ awk '$9=="PARAMFILE"{sub("/dirprm.*","",$10); print $10}' file
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

Or, if what you want is the first and not the last `/dirpm`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if s/.*PARAMFILE (.*?)\/dirprm.*/\1/' file
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU `grep` for the task with the `-P` option:

```bsh
$ grep -oP '(?<=PARAMFILE ).*(?=/dirprm)' /tmp/ggloc.log 
/oracle/gg
/oracle/GG_123012/GG_HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which can be useful, if you are not very interested to play with regular expressions:

`grep PARAMFILE file | tr -s ' ' | cut -f10 -d' '`

`grep` will give you just the lines with PARAMFILE.
`tr` will squeeze all spaces into one.
And finally `cut` will give you just the tenth word in the line.

Upd: As pointed to me in a comment - the first command does not remove the unneeded tail of the string. So here is a corrected version:

```
grep PARAMFILE q | tr -s ' ' | cut -f10 -d' '| sed 's/\/dirprm\/mgr.prm//'
```

Sorry, I do not see how to avoid obvious use of regular expressions.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output stated by OP since prints the `.prm` files.